# Powershell - using machine-agnostic SecureString via AES Key - password not decrypting correctly

Tags: powershell, encryption, aes

I need to create a portable set of key files and password files to allow multiple Windows-based systems to use the same set of credentials.

I am using this script to create the key file and the encrypted password file:

```
#==========================================================================
# 
# Define variables
$Directory = "C:\some_path\Powershell_Scripts"
$KeyFile = Join-Path $Directory  "AES_KEY_FILE.key"
$PasswordFile = Join-Path $Directory "AES_PASSWORD_FILE.txt"
# 
# Text for the console
Write-Host "Enter password and press ENTER:"
$Password = Read-Host -AsSecureString
# 
Write-Host ""
# 
# Create the AES key file
try {
 $Key = New-Object Byte[] 32
 [Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create().GetBytes($Key)
 $Key | out-file $KeyFile
        $KeyFileCreated = $True
 Write-Host "The key file $KeyFile was created successfully"
} catch {
 write-Host "An error occurred trying to create the key file $KeyFile (error: $($Error[0])"
}
Start-Sleep 2
# Add the plaintext password to the password file (and encrypt it based on the AES key file)
If ( $KeyFileCreated -eq $True ) {
 try {
 $Key = Get-Content $KeyFile
 $Password = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
 $Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString -key $Key | Out-File $PasswordFile
 Write-Host "The key file $PasswordFile was created successfully"
 } catch {
 write-Host "An error occurred trying to create the password file $PasswordFile (error: $($Error[0])"
 }
}
Write-Host ""
write-Host "End of script (press any key to quit)"
```

This appears to work flawlessly.

I use the following code to use the encrypted password to attach to remote shares:

```
$Directory = "C:\some_path\Powershell_Scripts"
$KeyFile = Join-Path $Directory  "AES_KEY_FILE.key"
$PasswordFile = Join-Path $Directory "AES_PASSWORD_FILE.txt"
$Username = 'localhost\some_username' # a local Administrator account
try {
 $Key = New-Object Byte[] 32
 [Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create().GetBytes($Key)
 $Key = Get-Content $KeyFile
 $Password = Get-Content $PasswordFile
 $Password = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $Key
 $MyCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, (Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key)
}
Catch {
    'Something bad happened!'
}
New-PSDrive -Credential $MyCredential -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\localhost\d$" -name "P"
```

The 'New-PSDrive' command is consistently resulting in the message "The network path was not found."
When I attempt to decrypt the password by converting the encrypted password to a PSCredential Object, using the following commands,

```
$s = $MyCredential.GetNetworkCredential()
$t = $s.password
```

$t remains a System.Security.SecureString

If I do the following:

```
$m = Get-Credential
$n = $m.GetNetworkCredential()
$o = $n.password
```

then $o returns a clear-text password.

What am I doing incorrectly which is resulting in the System.Security.SecureString instead of it providing the clear-text password?

I do have code which correctly encrypts and decrypts a password to/from a file, but the file is machine and user account specific.  It is as follows:

```
$runtime = Get-Date -Format ('yyyyMMddHHss')
$PwdFile = 'D:\Some_Folder\Encrypted.PWD'
$Creds = Get-Credential
$SecurePwd = $Creds.Password
$ExportPwd = ConvertFrom-SecureString $SecurePwd
$ExportPwd | Out-File $PwdFile
$TestPwd = Get-Content $PwdFile
$TestSecPwd = $TestPwd | ConvertTo-SecureString
$TestCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Creds.UserName, $TestSecPwd
$TestGetCred = $TestCred.GetNetworkCredential()
$TestClrPwd = $TestGetCred.Password
"The clear text password is " + $TestClrPwd
```

Comment: Give a read here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2010/09/21/decrypt-secure-strings-in-powershell/

Comment: I did look at using Bstr.  Unfortunately, it, too, is not correctly decrypting the string.

Comment: I do have code which works but it is tied to a specific user account/machine.  I will post this code in the main question as it looks like trash as a comment.

Comment: I discovered my error, I think.
    $Password = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
is a redundant encryption as $Password is read from the host as a System.Security.SecureString.  I commented this line from the first code block and can now correctly read the agnostic password on the same machine.

Comment: Unfortunately, removing the above-mentioned line did not resolve the issue.